# Google script to recognize new workbook created

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

I would like to have a standalone script that could recognize when a new workbook was created by a user.

Can someone point me in the right direction> TIA

Comment: I assume when you say workbook you mean spreadsheet. Also, do you want the date this spreadsheet was created in the past? Or every time a new spreadsheet is created by a specific user you want to get the timestamp of the creation date ? Generally, you need to have at least view access to the spreadsheet files to see the creation date.

Comment: That's a fairly complex problem; ie. tracking when a new workbook is created in real-time (across multiple users).The only thing that comes to mind is to use Drive API Push notifications. Unfortunately, its not possible to use GAS web apps as web-hook endpoints for Google API push notifications. However, you can use a 'serverless' solution such as Google Cloud Functions, but that will take you well outside the realm of your typical GAS program.

Comment: Yes-I meant spreadsheet., I don't care about the creation date. What my overall objective is to monitor all spreadsheets from multiple users to detect onChange evwnts and do a post via API to an external website. Assuming I figure out how to do that, whenever a new spreadsheet is created, I want to add that to the spreadsheets that I am monitoring for change events. Assume that permission (View access) is not an issue.

Comment: I'd move on to your next problem.  There's no trigger that will provide what you want.  The only thing you can do is to use a timebased trigger and poll for files with Date Created the same as today.  I personally would suggest that whomever wants it learn to live without it and move on to another problem.